# Rails - how to automatically uniq joins method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This question is based on this: [Rails, why joins returns array with non-uniq values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174875/rails-why-joins-returns-array-with-non-uniq-values)

Let say I get non uniq array by `.joins()` method:

```
City.joins(:locations)
# => [#<City id: 5, name: "moscow", created_at: "2010-07-02 15:09:16", updated_at: "2010-07-02 15:09:16">, #<City id: 5, name: "moscow", created_at: "2010-07-02 15:09:16", updated_at: "2010-07-02 15:09:16">, #<City id: 5, name: "moscow", created_at: "2010-07-02 15:09:16", updated_at: "2010-07-02 15:09:16">, #<City id: 5, name: "moscow", created_at: "2010-07-02 15:09:16", updated_at: "2010-07-02 15:09:16">]
```

I can make records uniq by using

```
City.joins(:locations).group('cities.id') # or simpler
City.joins(:locations).uniq
# => [#<City id: 5, name: "moscow", created_at: "2010-07-02 15:09:16", updated_at: "2010-07-02 15:09:16">]
```

How can I make `.joins()` method returns uniq records by default?

Comment: how about `has_many :locations, -> { joins(:locations).uniq }` ?

Comment: Can it change the behaviour of AR queires in another places? Seems exactly how I want...

Comment: yes. it  change the `sql` query of `has_many` macro and can be run on an object only.

Comment: What do you mean by `can be run on the project only`?

Comment: не `project` a `object`

Comment: can i post my comment as an answer? Do you find it helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try overriding the `.joins` method for the models you need, but I would suggest just writing a scope, e.g.

```
scope :unique_locations, -> { joins(:locations).uniq }
```

Then just call `City.unique_locations`. It's cleaner and more readable that way.

Generally overwriting methods should be done only when you're sure you won't need it 'the old way', and it makes sense. Plus, when you say `City.joins(:locations)` the reader expects default behaviour, and returning something else will cause chaos and confusion.

Comment: Hm.. Interesting idea. Maybe, there is another way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can define `has_many` macro, with the `stubby` lambda as an argument:

```
has_many :locations, -> { joins(:locations).uniq }
```

Also you can define own AR relation method, it stil use a simple `has_many` macro.

```
has_many :locations do
  def only_uniq     
    joins(:locations).uniq
  end
end
```

Now use it:

```
c = City.find(123)
c.locations.only_uniq
```

It does the same thing as `scope` or `lambda` in `has_many`.